# Кликабельный элемент страницы вопроса перезагружает её

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, дизайн

Имеется элемент на странице вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при наведении появляется тултип а при нажатии просто перезагружается страница. Не зная об этом поведении я честно говоря думал что я увижу что-то типа истории правок или что-то такое. Может имеет смысл убрать кликабельность данного элемента или данное поведение так и задумывалось?

Comment: AFAIK так и задумывалось.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, тогда в чем смысл этой штуки?) просто перезагружать страницу?)

Comment: Это вроде ссылка на сам вопрос. Это не рефреш.

Comment: Это ссылка на элемент, в котором произошла последняя активность. Если последняя активность была в вопросе — то она ведёт на вопрос. Но иногда она может вести на ответ.

Comment: @andreymal, вот это уже более предметный разговор)) просто при первом тычке немного не понял логику поведения)

Comment: @andreymal запостите как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ссылка на элемент, в котором произошла последняя активность. Если последняя активность была в вопросе — то она ведёт на вопрос. Но иногда она может вести на ответ.